# How to get wordpress custom post data in json?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

In my template file i fetch the custom post data like this ,

[image]

Initially I fetch 7 post, I need to make a read more button bellow the post, which will fetch more 7 posts from the wp database table, when someone click on it.

But I don't know how to do it, I want to know about,

- In jquery get method, which php file i call for the data,
- How or what exact script i will write in that php file.

Comment: Create a ajax function in function.php , and pass offset value to it through ajax call and just append the received data in your disply section.

Comment: hey bro , can you give the answer in more details please ... @Balwant

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here i have added a rough idea how you can write your code :

Create a ajax function in function.php , and pass offset value to it through ajax call and just append the received data in your disply section.

here is an example of creating ajax function :

```
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_cyt_ajax_search','cyt_ajax_search');
add_action('wp_ajax_cyt_ajax_search','cyt_ajax_search');
function cyt_ajax_search(){


    $offset = $_POST['offset'];

    $args = array (
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'posts_per_page' =>7
    'offset'=>$offset,

    'meta_query' =>..........

    );
$query = new WP_Query($args);
if($query->have_posts() ) : 
        while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); 


endwhile; 

wp_reset_postdata();
endif; 


}
```

//Frontend code , on button click it will cal the ajax function and pass the offset value, on each click you need  to increase the value by 7 (in case you want to load 7 post only ) and check how many post  are left and if offset value exceedded the no of total counted data to be display by wp query then simply hide the button

```html
<div id ="esiSection"></div>

<span click="loadmore" data-offset='0'>Click here</span>  

jQuery('.loadmore').click(function(){ 
var offset = parseInt(jQuery(this).attr('data-offset'));
jQuery.ajax({    
   url: '<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>',
   type: 'POST',    
   data: { 
    'action' : 'cyt_ajax_search',  
    'offset' : offset ,
   },
  success: function(response) {
  
   jQuery('#resiSection').append(response);
   offset = offset + 7;
 
   
  },
  error: function(error){
   console.log(error);
   
  }
    
 }); 
 
});
```