# Setting offset load more button for custom post types in Wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I have custom post types displaying on a static front page, initially showing 8 posts, where I have now created a load more button using an example of jQuery and AJAX  that I found online that will show 4 more posts when the button is clicked. I am wondering how I can add 4 to the offset each time so it keeps moving through the next posts. As it is now every time I click the load more button it shows the same 4 over again. My code in my front-page.php:

```
<script>
var now=2; // when click start in page 2

jQuery(document).on('click', '#load_more_btn', function () {

    jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "<?php echo get_site_url(); ?>/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
        data: {
            action: 'my_load_more_function', // the name of the function in functions.php
            paged: now, // set the page to get the ajax request
            posts_per_page: 4,  //number of post to get (use 1 for testing)
        },
        success: function (data) {

        if(data!=0){
            jQuery("#ajax").append(data);  // put the content into ajax container
            now=now+1; // add 1 to next page
        }else{
               jQuery("#load_more_btn").html("<h4>No more 
results</h4>");
        }
        },
        error: function (errorThrown) {
            alert(errorThrown); // only for debuggin
        }
    });
});
```

and the code in my functions.php file:

```
add_action('wp_ajax_my_load_more_function', 'my_load_more_function');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_my_load_more_function', 
'my_load_more_function');

 function my_load_more_function() {
    $offset = 8;
    $page = (get_query_var('page')) ? get_query_var('page') : 1;
    $query = new WP_Query( [
    'posts_per_page' => $_POST["posts_per_page"],
    'order'=>'ASC',
    'offset'=> $offset,
    'post_type' => 'videos',
    'page' => get_query_var('page', $_POST["paged"])
] );

if ($query->have_posts()) {
    $offset = (($page - 1) * 8) - $offset;
    $query->set( 'offset', $offset );

    while ($query->have_posts()) {
            $query->the_post();  
         $img1 = get_field('video_thumbnail'); ?>
        <div class="col-6 col-sm-3 box no-gutters" style="background-
image: url('<?php echo $img1['url']; ?>')"><a href="<?php 
the_field('video_link'); ?>" data-lity><div class="overlay"><span 
class="title"><?php the_field('name'); ?></span></div></a></div>
<?php 
 }
    wp_reset_query();
}else{
    return 0;
}
exit;
}
```

I'm wondering how I can get offset to be +4 each time the query is run after the initial time where it is set at 8. I'm fairly new to thsi type of thing and can not seem to get it working properly.

Comment: Please check this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46722405/how-to-get-wordpress-custom-post-data-in-json/46722806?noredirect=1#comment80392249_46722806

Comment: You do not need offset. Just use `posts_per_page` and `paged`. Quoting from WP Codex:

"Specifying hard-coded offsets in queries can and will break pagination since offset is used by WordPress internally to calculate and handle pagination."

https://codex.wordpress.org/Making_Custom_Queries_using_Offset_and_Pagination

Comment: @HaktanSuren any idea or reference you could point me to as how to implement that? I am using custom post types on a static front page and am having issues using pages there. I'm also fairly new to all of this.

Comment: @Balwant thanks, I tried what was in that post but still no luck.

Comment: @jessicamele first of all remove `'offset'=> $offset,` form the query array. and then please print `get_query_var('page', $_POST["paged"])`. Maybe you are not properly collecting page info there?